# Kannel: Cannot Send or receive SMS

Tags: linux, mobile, sms, modem, kannel

I am trying to send and receive SMS via kannel. I have set everything, no errors but still it cannot send or receive any sms.
I am using Huawei E160 modem and Ubuntu 11 as my OS.
Here is the log file:

```
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13000.
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: BOXC: 'smsbox-max-pending' not set, using default (100).
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <(null)> disabled.
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: configuration shows modemtype <huawei>
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: read modem definition for <huawei-e160>
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [6] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: opening device
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: Adding interface *
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [6] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: Logging in
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [6] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: init device
2012-02-25 14:25:34 [9913] [6] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: speed set to 115200
2012-02-25 14:25:35 [9913] [6] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyUSB0]: AT SMSC successfully opened.
2012-02-25 14:26:28 [9913] [13] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1>
```

My kannel.conf file

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = 123
status-password = 123
smsbox-port = 13003
wapbox-port = 13004
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_core.log"
log-level = 1
wdp-interface-name = "*"

#group = smsc
#smsc = fake
#port = 1000

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_smsbox.log"
log-level = 1

group = smsc
smsc = at   
modemtype = huawei
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
speed=115200
log-level = 0        
pin = 1442

group = modems 
id = huawei
name = "huawei-e160" 
detect-string = "huawei" 
init-string = "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0" 
speed = 115200

group = wapbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_wapbox.log"

group = sendsms-user
username = 123
password = 123
user-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = "http://localhost/kannel/receivesms.php?sender=%p&amp;text=%b"
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
max-messages = 3
concatenation = true
catch-all = true
```

My receivesms.php file is coded as

```
<?php

define("DBHOST","localhost",true);

define("DBUSERNAME","root",true);

define("DBPASSWORD","xxxxxx",true);

define("DBNAME","kannel_sms",true);


function insertSms($sender,$text)

{   

    $con = 'mysql:dbname='.DBNAME.';host='.DBHOST;

    try {

        $cmd = new PDO($con,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWORD);
        $stmt = $cmd->prepare("INSERT INTO kannel_tuto (number,message) VALUES (:sender,:message)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':sender',$sender);
        $stmt->bindParam(':message',$text);

        $stmt->execute();

        $cmd = null;

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)

        {

               echo "Hello ".$text.". Thank you for your registration.";

        }

        else

        {

            echo "Sorry an error has occured";

        }

        }        

        catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

} 

insertSms($_GET['sender'],$_GET['text']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated above, my script and configurations are correct. I just figured out that the E160 modem is not good for sms and kannel. There is loss of signals, I don't know why though. I used E173 and E220 huawei modems and they work well.